# How to read file through jenkins from github

Tags: github, jenkins, file-exists, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to read a file from github using `readFile`,

```
                        sshagent (credentials: ["${github_cred}"]) {
                        script {
                                sh """
                                    git checkout test_branch
                                """
                               def file = readFile(file: "/myrepo/${params.value}.txt")
```

But in other case, this file will not be available for certain parameters passed. So I would like to check if the file exists in github and proceed with the next steps if it is available or else it should skip the stage.

**First Try:**

When I try to do with the above code, it is throwing `NoSuchFileException` when it is not available. I tried with `fileExists` function which actually works only on the controller node, not on the github. Is there any possible to achieve this?

**Second Try:**

I also tried with `git show` as below but I got `illegal string body or character after dollar sign` error, I don't know what is wrong here.

`git show HEAD~1:/myrepo/"${params.value}".txt > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fileExists` should run in the current node the Pipeline is running on. So it should ideally work.

```
if (fileExists("/myrepo/${params.value}.txt") {
   def file = readFile(file: "/myrepo/${params.value}.txt") 
}
```

Another easy workaround is to wrap your `readFile` with a try-cath given you know readFile will fail if the file is not available.

```
def isSuccess = true
def file = null

try {
 file = readFile(file: "/myrepo/${params.value}.txt") 
}catch(e) {
 isSuccess = false
}
```

Comment: Again this try-catch will execute on the current node not on the github right? I am checking out the branch in `sh` and in that case I need to go with the `script`

Comment: @Alfred everything will execute in the Jenkins node. So yes you need to first checkout the code and then check the existence of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins machine is windows or macos or linux?

```
sh """

pwd
git checkout test_branch
"""
```

In case it's linux or macos add pwd to see the local full path of the repo
And then use this full path in the readfile

Comment: Actually, it is working for the available file, but I would like to know more about how to work on condition when the file is not available in github. How do we check if the file exists in github from jenkins?